# Convert square braced substrings in text into an associative array

Tags: php, regex, string, associative-array, text-extraction

I have a PHP script that parses pieces of info out of `argv[]` but am a bit confused as to how to get info out of a long string. I just want the `[msg "something something"]` & `[uri "something something"]`

The string:

> [Wed Feb 06 08:57:54 2019] [error] [client 123.123.123.123]
> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator EQ
> matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file
> "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"]
> [line "47"] [id "960015"] [rev "1"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept
> Header"] [severity "NOTICE"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.6"] [maturity "9"]
> [accuracy "9"] [tag
> "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_ACCEPT"] [tag
> "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname
> "something.net"] [uri "/index.php/admin/"] [unique_id
> "XFsEAsDzZbMAAGY5i5oAAAAA"]

Comment: Please post actual examples of what should be captured. Please also show what you have tried. `[msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"]` and `[uri "/index.php/admin/"] ` are what you need?

Comment: Correct. The [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] and [uri "/index.php/admin/"] are what I need to extract. With mod_security being what it is, it has a tendency to spit out very wordy strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with regex pattern match like below- [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/5/)

```
<?php
$re = '`\[(msg|uri) "(.*?)"\]`mi';
$str = '[Wed Feb 06 08:57:54 2019] [error] [client 123.123.123.123] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "47"] [id "960015"] [rev "1"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "NOTICE"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.6"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_ACCEPT"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "something.net"] [uri "/index.php/admin/"] [unique_id "XFsEAsDzZbMAAGY5i5oAAAAA"]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// matches contains all full match, partial match, so you can use any index to get that values e.g match[0] contains [uri "/index.php/admin/"]
//print_r($matches); // see what is full match, partial match etc
foreach($matches as $match){
    $expected[] = $match[2];
}
print_r($expected);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Request Missing an Accept Header 
    [1] => /index.php/admin/ 
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/HJ2uB

Comment: The `m` in the pattern modifier list is pointless because there are no `^` or `$` metacharacters in the pattern.  `m` does not affect `.` (but `.` is affected by `s`).

Answer (score 2):

By using a broad regex, you can extract all the tag information at once. You can then use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to produce an array of values indexed by the tag:

```
preg_match_all('/\[([a-z_]+)\s*([^]]*)\]/', $string, $matches);
$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [error] =>
    [client] => 123.123.123.123
    [file] => "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"
    [line] => "47"
    [id] => "960015"
    [rev] => "1"
    [msg] => "Request Missing an Accept Header"
    [severity] => "NOTICE"
    [ver] => "OWASP_CRS/2.2.6"
    [maturity] => "9"
    [accuracy] => "9"
    [tag] => "PCI/6.5.10"
    [hostname] => "something.net"
    [uri] => "/index.php/admin/"
    [unique_id] => "XFsEAsDzZbMAAGY5i5oAAAAA"
)
```

If you don't want quotes around the values, use `array_map` and `trim`:

```
$output = array_map(function ($v) { return trim($v, '"'); }, $output);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [error] =>
    [client] => 123.123.123.123
    [file] => /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf
    [line] => 47
    [id] => 960015
    [rev] => 1
    [msg] => Request Missing an Accept Header
    [severity] => NOTICE
    [ver] => OWASP_CRS/2.2.6
    [maturity] => 9
    [accuracy] => 9
    [tag] => PCI/6.5.10
    [hostname] => something.net
    [uri] => /index.php/admin/
    [unique_id] => XFsEAsDzZbMAAGY5i5oAAAAA
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/l6bvS)

Answer (score -1):

To harvest all of the data pairs from the text as an associative array with unquoted values, use `preg_match_all()` then `array_column()`.

- Capture group 1 will hold the keys,
- Capture group 2 will isolate optional leading quote
- Capture group 3 will hold the unquoted values
- The `\2` will ensure that the trailing quote is isolated if there was a leading quote.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nhgEY))

```
preg_match_all('/\[([a-z]+) +("?)(.*?)(\2)]/', $text, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_export(
    array_column($m, 3, 1)
);
```

If you only want `msg` and `uri`, then add those explicitly to the first capture group.
`/\[(msg|uri) +("?)(.*?)\2]/` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/AKJ3i)

Comment: Ah, right, the ole no-comment-dv on the most refined, provably correct answer on the page.  That makes perfect sense.  Good work voter!